# Group Theory: relation between subgroups

Tags: group-theory

i would like to ask how to show the following exercise
"Let H and H' two subgroups of G (G not necessary finite).These subgroups are called isometries if the ensemble H ∩ H' has finite index towards H and H'.Show that isometry relation is an equivalence relation for the subgroups of G."

Comment: To show that it is equivalence relation, you need to verify three properties, reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity. Which of those three properties are you having problems checking?

Comment: I have problem to show reflexivity and symmetry.Can you help with this?

Comment: So we want to show that the relation $H\cong H'$ defined by $[H,H\cap H']$ and $[H,H\cap H']$ being finite as an equivalance relation? So you need to show that $H\cong H'\implies H'\cong H$, $H\cong H$, and if $H \cong H'$ and $H'\cong H^*$ then $H\cong H^*$.

Comment: Reflexivity and symmetry seem obvious. Transitivity is harder. So no I don't think I can help!

Comment: Ok thanks for your time.Could you tell me how to show transivity to see if i did it wright?Thank you you very much,again!